# Spring Annotation based AOP to intercept method implemented in parent class

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

We are using annotation based AOP for methods to intercept functionality.

Base interface:

```
public interface BaseInterface { 
    public void someMethod();
}
```

Abstract Base implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseImplementation implements BaseInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
       //some logic
    }
}
```

Child interface:

```
public interface ChildInterface extends BaseInterface {
  public void anotherMethod();
}
```

Implementation Class

```
public class ActualImplemetation extends AbstractBaseImplementation implements ChildInterface {

   public void anotherMethod() {
     // Some logic
   }
}
```

There are many classes extended from the `AbstractBaseImplementation`. Custom Annotation is created for identifying the point cuts.

Aspect is

```
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

  @Before("@annotation(customAnnotation)")
  public void someMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
     //Intercept logic
  }

}
```

How can we intercept `ActualImplemetation.someMethod` (Which is implemented in the parent class) using Annotation based AOP?

Using aop configuration this can be achieved by

```
<aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.package..*ActualImplemetation .someMethod(..))" advice-ref="someInterceptor" />
```

Comment: Did you read the [documents](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/aop.html)? It's all described there with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like :

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.package.*ActualImplemetation.someMethod(..))"
// OR
// using BaseInterface reference directly, you can use all sub-interface/sub-class methods
//@Pointcut("execution(* com.package.BaseInterface.someMethod(..))"
logMethod() { //ignore method syntax
 //.....
}
```

Comment: I am using custom annotation for identifying the point cut. My interceptor is like,  @Before("@annotation(customAnnotation)") method() {}

Comment: @Sujith : I never used custom annotation but I don't think your way is going to work. Why don't you make it simple and just write expression in `@Before` annotation as above?

Comment: custom Annotation will help to add new methods very easily. Otherwise we will have to modify the interceptor for adding new methods.

Comment: @Sujith : You are in wrong direction. See Abhinav's link in comment to your question. Read it carefully.

Comment: I am able to execute the Custom annotation AOP for all other scenario. But failed on this specific scenario. I have implemented this based on the below tutorial http://thoughtforge.net/665/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/

Answer (score 1):

This should work with some modification:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@CustomAnnotation * *(..))")
public void customAnnotationAnnotatedMethods() {/**/}   


@Before("customAnnotationAnnotatedMethods()")
public void adviceBeforeCustomAnnotation() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where should we place Custom annotation (@CustomAnnotation) for the specific abstract method (ActualImplemetation.someMethod). The problem is that it is not required in all implementation class.

Comment: You can place the annotation where ever you have the implementation of the method that is expected to be covered by this annotation