# inject my code before/after service call using annotations

Tags: java, annotations, interceptor

The service is a spring bean, it is @autowired into my class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    private void myMethod() {
        service.call();
    }
}
```

The call() method may throw exceptions, so I wrap it with try-catch lines:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    private void myMethod() {
        try {
            service.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do some logging
        }
    }
}
```

how can I write an custom annotation and do this automatically? like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Monitored
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    private void myMethod() {
        // it will be logged if call() throws exception
        service.call();
    }
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to fire code each time the method is called, have you looked into Spring AOP much?  This seems like a perfect use case.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples, such as [Spring Annotation based AOP to intercept method implemented in parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670617/spring-annotation-based-aop-to-intercept-method-implemented-in-parent-class) or [Spring annotation based AOP and intercepting the ball](http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/02/03/spring-annotation-based-aop-and-intercepting-the-ball/).

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `advice` for your desired method. And define a `point-cut` for your method which you want to be intercepted. Look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop-api.html) for more information about different types of advice (I believe in your case `Before` and `After` or `Around` is suitable) and some examples.